# Angular 5 does not check multiple conditions

Tags: angular

I create a method to submit a form, and inside that method I have to check 2 conditions which are created in 2 different other methods before submitting the form, but I don't even know why, only the first condition is triggered, the second one is never called, no matter which conditional method I put first. Can anyone explains this, I could not even find a similar problem on the Internet?

component.ts:

```
onSubmit(formValues) {
  if (editedForm.status === 'Ready') {
    // no matter what conditional method is called first, only the 
    // first condition is checked
    if (this.isNotOverlapped() && this.isValidPeriodOrder()) {
      this.apiService.submit(formValues).subscribe(() => {
       // sending data to backend....
      });
    }
  }
}

// conditional method
isNotOverlapped(): boolean {
  console.log('IsNotOverlapped fire!');
  let isvalid = false;
  if (this.data.length > 1) {
   // some validation stuffs
  }
  return isvalid;
}

// conditional method
isValidPeriodOrder(): boolean {
  console.log('IsValidPeriodOrder fire!');
  let isvalid = false;
  if (this.data.length > 1) {
   // some validation stuffs
  }
  return isvalid;
}
```

Comment: so you are saying isNotOverlapped() and isValidPeriodOrder() are not being checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `isNotOverlapped()` is always returning `false`, then the second condition will never called.

For example:

`if(condition1 && condition2 && ...)`

If any condition is false, no other remaining will be verified. Try to force the `isNotOverlapped()` to return true and check it.